# Matlab Error"Array indices must be positive integers or logical values"

Tags: matlab

I'm new to matlab and trying to express the function:

> > f(z)=(1-exp((1+v)./z)).*(z./y).*cos(z)

with the values: >> v=3.4 >> y=6.9 >> z=8:1.21:328.65

but always get the error message "Array indices must be positive integers or logical values."

Please help

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing f(z) into matlab it means z index of array f. You need to say r = (1-exp((1+v)./z)).*(z./y).*cos(z):

```
v = 3.4;
y = 6.9;
z=8:1.21:328.65;
f = (1-exp((1+v)./z)).*(z./y).*cos(z);
```